# Whipping cream that has been frozen won't whip

Tags: frozen, whipped-cream, mistakes

I have whipping cream that has been frozen; it is now separated and won't whip. Is there anything I can do to make it whip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can heavy cream be frozen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/can-heavy-cream-be-frozen)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, no.

Whipping cream that has been frozen is perfectly fine to use in many dishes, but it won't whip.

As far as I know, this is irreversible, so no, you can't make the cream "whipable". If you are very lucky, you will get it to a sort of semi-stiff stage, but nothing that would be suitable for cake decorating or similar.

---

Not part of your question, but possibly interesting for next time:
*Whipped* cream can be frozen, so if you have leftovers, you could pipe little tufts or similar, freze them and use them to decorate desserts.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be mixed experiences of whether or not frozen cream can be whipped: [this discussion thread](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/can-i-freeze-cream-heavy-whipping/) has voices on both sides. Note that those who say it can be whipped talk about possibly needing to re-emulsify it. If I were to try to whip frozen cream I would add some soy lecithin to try to help with the emulsification.

Answer (score -2):

just add a bit of powdered sugar and whip as usual.